# Reactjs use ref on parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this on `reactjs` in a functional component:

```
const searchTitle = useRef();

<FormGroup className={'filterItems p-3 active'} ref={searchTitle}>
   <div onClick={()=> handleTitleToggle()}>
   </div>          
</FormGroup>
```

And want to toggle class on `FormGroup` via click on div.

```
const handleTitleToggle = () => {
    searchTitle.current.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

But give me error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

But if I use `ref` on div, it works fine, any idea?

```
<div ref={searchTitle} onClick={()=> handleTitleToggle()}>
</div>
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to do this with a ref? The standard approach would be to use state. Direct manipulation of the dom is rarely a good idea in react.

Comment: @NicholasTower Just for toggling class easily, that's all. but I'm wondering how can I do this via `ref` .. still learning

Comment: Don't use a ref for this, a re-render will undo your manual DOM manipulations. Instead, keep track of which form is [active with some _id_, and check before applying the class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64586750/1218980).

Answer (score -1):

if you are using MUI FormGroup Component be sure that it accept ref
and when you have chain of props on you object use optional chaining to avoid errors like this

```
searchTitle?.current?.classList?.toggle('active')
```